# PHP ZendOptimizer on Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Tags: php, redhat, zend

I would like to install FlashMoto and the requirements are not unreasonable: PHP 5.2.1 or higher, Zend Optimizer 3.3 or higher. However my RHEL 5.4 provides me with PHP 5.1.6. So I tried the remi repository http://rpms.famillecollet.com/ but it gave me PHP 5.3.1 and Zend Optimizer from zend.com does not support anything higher than 5.2.x. I also tried the dag repo but it does not have PHP in any version. I also tried some RPMs that Oracle provides on their homepage but they don't provide php-mbstring that I also need. Does anyone know how to get PHP 5.2.1 installed on a RHEL 5.4? Then I can probably fix install the Zend thing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My company uses [Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/products/server/) on its RHEL 5 servers. It's a PHP stack distributed by Zend. It's available in 5.2 and 5.3 versions, with a free 'community edition' and a commercial edition with additional features. If you're serving websites commercially, these additional features are very useful in my opinion. Both editions come with most PHP extensions you'll need, and have Zend Optimizer+ included.

I have good experiences with both editions. They have an rpm repo you can install and update from.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. http://forums.famillecollet.com/viewtopic.php?id=88 Basically Remi maintains a repo of Red Hat software that is already at PHP 5.3.3 but he has an archive from which I downloaded the rpm files. These are the steps i took:
Removed PHP.
New PHP could not install because of conflicts between new mysqli old mysql. Removed mysql - Remi's archive contains the mysql rpms as well.
Installed PHP and MySQL from Remi's archive.
Merged the old configfiles php.ini.rpmsave, my.cnf.rpmsave into the new ones.
Had to dump/reload some tables in MySQL because of the upgrade.
Installed zendoptimizer from standard repo.
Installed flashmoto.